# how do i modify a global variable in makefile?

Tags: makefile

i have something like this in my makefile :

```
JAR = jar1.jar

run:
    java -cp $(JAR)
```

what i want to do is for the makefile to do `run` multiple times but with each iteration, it uses another jar, they're all called jarx.jar with x going from 1 to 10 for example

is it possible to do it without passing the jar name inside the statement? the example i gave is quite simple for the sake of simplicity but the actual makefile i'm working with is already quite complicated...

Comment: It is not exactly clear if you want to "do `run`" in one invocation of make. If yes, do you want this to be parallelizable?

Comment: Do you mean `run: for f in jar1 jartwo third; do java -cp $$f.jar; done` in a single recipe?

Comment: @Vroomfondel i want them to run sequentially @triplee more or less like that, but instead of doing `java -cp $$f.jar` i want to call a make rule

Answer (score 1):

`make` uses filesystem objects to keep state. A common solution to keeping track of things which are not directly visible as files in the current directory is to create a local flag file.

```
JARS := first.jar 2nd.jar thirdjar.jar

.PHONY: all run
all: $(patsubst %, .made-%,$(JARS))
run: all

.made-%.jar: %.jar
    java -cp $<
    touch $@
```

So the existence of `.made-first.jar` signals to Make that this target has been performed for the prerequisite `first.jar`, etc.

If you have a `clean` target, or at least `realclean`, it should probably clean up all the flag files.